# How to get mids from freebase

Tags: freebase

I wanted to know is there any way to retrieve Mids from freebase by query on name, place of birth and years of birth ...

I know that, I can use query like:

```
query={"type":"/people/person"%2C"id":null%2C"name":"Susan%20Sarandon"%2C"date_of_birth":"1946-10-04"}
```

and it gives me the: `"id" = "/en/susan_sarandon"`
but I want: `"id": "/m/01vwllw"`

And also I need to know `date_of_birth`, but I only know the place of birth and year of birth and death. Another problem is that I am not sure about the way that they stored the names. I mean it is always something like "Susan Sarandon" or it could be "Susan_Sarandon"?

Comment: `Another problem is that I am not sure about the way that they stored the names.` That's something you'll have to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just ask for an ID, Freebase will give you whatever it thinks is best.  If you explicitly want an MID (or GUID), you can ask for them, e.g.

```
[{
  "type": "/people/person",
  "mid": null,
  "name": "Susan Sarandon",
  "date_of_birth": "1946-10-04"
}]
```

Comment: thanks. but is there any way to retrieve the MID from "place_of_birth" and/or "place_of_death" instead of using "date_of_birth"? because I don't have exactly the data of birth, I only have the Year of birth and death. I search for it in freebase but I couldn't find it!